# Estimating heritability from twin studies--How to get it?

Tags: regression-coefficients, genetics, gwas

I was learning the concept of heritability, and come to the Falconer's formula:

$h^2=2(r_{MZ}-r_{DZ})$                                (1)

Where $r_{MZ}$ and $r_{DZ}$ are correlation coefficients of the phenotypes between monozygous twins and heterozygous twins, respectively.

However, I tried to get this formula by myself, and got confused:

1. For the twin studies, when you calculate r correlation coefficients, if the references were random, then r should always be close to 1. So there should be a rule to choose $Y^{(1)}$ and $Y^{(2)}$ for each twin-pairs, and apply correlation analysis after that. Then, what's that rule?
2. To my understanding, $r$ is defined as:

   $r = \frac{COV(Y_i^{(1)},Y_i^{(2)})}{\sigma(Y_{(i)}^1)\sigma(Y_i^{(2)})}$

   - For homozygous twins:

     $Y_i^{(1)}=X_i+\epsilon_i^{(1)}$

     $Y_i^{(2)}=X_i+\epsilon_i^{(2)}$
   - For heterozygous twins:

     $Y_i^{(1)}=0.5X_i+0.5D_i^{(1)}+\epsilon_i^{(1)}$

     $Y_i^{(2)}=0.5X_i+0.5D_i^{(2)}+\epsilon_i^{(2)}$

     Where Y are the phenotype, X are the contributions by shared genetics, D are the contributions by distinct genetics in heterozygous twins, and $\epsilon$ are the contributions by environments

Following these settings, I tried to deduce formula (1), but failed. Anyone could help? Very appreciate your help!

Thanks,

Raymond

Comment: I doubt your $Y_i^{(2)}=X_i+\epsilon_i^{(2)}$ and $Y_i^{(2)}=0.5X_i+0.5D_i^{(2)}+\epsilon_i^{(2)}$ work like that - it looks as if they have different variances

Comment: Thanks! I tried to understand, it looks like the correlation coefficients were mixed with concepts in ANOVA analysis, and a lot researcher seem to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a different way of building an intuition for heritability.

The genetic relatedness of identical twins is 1, and for fraternal it is 0.5. We can make two points to illustrate both the genetic relatedness, and the twin study results (for a continuous variable).
(1, The phenotypic correlation among monozygotic twins)
(0.5, The phenotypic correlation among dizygotic twins

Given genetic relatedness (1 for mz identical twin, 0.5 for dz fraternal twin) on the $x$ axis and twin correlation for the phenotype on the $y$ axis, we can define these two points:
$$\begin{align}
(x_1, y_1) &= (0.5, r_{dz})\\
(x_2, y_2) &= (1, r_{mz})
\end{align}
$$

Can you think of how heritability might be represented given these two points? Think about how you'd expect the points to change as heritability changes.

Let r be the sample correlation coefficient.

Then, we can write the line between them in the two-point form:
$$(y - y_1) = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}  (x - x_1)$$
$$(y - r_{dz}) = \frac{r_{mz} - r_{dz}}{1 - 0.5} (x - 0.5)$$
Therefore, the slope is $\frac{r_{mz} - r_{dz}}{1 - 0.5} = 2(r_{mz}-r_{dz})$, which is equal to the broad-sense heritability.

Can you see how this bounds heritability naturally between 0 and 1, and how "difference" between r_mz and r_dz is built in?